# How to prevent black screen on MacBook Pro in the future

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, screen

For a while now, my 2017 MacBook Pro has had issues with turning on after shutting down.

Whenever I attempt to shut it down, it can never fully do so by itself it seems and I always have to force-shut it down using the power button. Then, when I turn it on again, the laptop turns on but shows only a black screen, preventing me from doing anything or signing in. Every time this has happened, I have then turned on my laptop in macOS Recovery and used Disk Utility to repair volumes, containers and then disks (following [the instructions given by Apple on its website](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210898)). After that, my laptop turns on just fine and the black screen is gone.

My question is: how can I prevent this issue in the future? I have no idea what application or system extension or thing is causing this problem, so I don't know what to do or delete. Is there a way to check?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, restart into Safe Boot mode (hold shift at start). Then see if it will shutdown and restart normally. If so: then you know it is not a hardware issue.

You may also want to reset the NVRAM.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063

Next, I would recommend using [EtreCheck](https://etrecheck.com/en/index.html), which is an application that produces a report of the 'state' of your Mac, including any background processes that are running.

If you paste the report here (it contains no personal details), then someone might spot something that needs attention. Otherwise, remove anything that you don't need; and make sure everything else is up-to-date.

Alternatively, this might be one of the rare situations when a 'clean' install is useful: Erase the volume, install the OS, and then only migrate your data and settings. Finish off the process by manually copying/downloading/installing the apps that you need.